# Abrir Perfil Firefox con Selenium 3.0

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Abre un perfil de Firefox, inicia en el navegador una pagina web.

Tengo este codigo que me funciona para abrir firefox e ir a la pagina pero no lo hace en el perfil especifico. Podrian por favor darme una ayuda, ya agoté todos los tutoriales. gracias

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class MM {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\MM\\Desktop\\fbc\\lib\\geckodriver.exe");

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette",true);

    try{
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        Thread.sleep(1800);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido Marcos,

En selenium 3 los profiles se añaden a las opciones de Firefox de la siguiente forma:

```
// Esta es tu linea que fija el gecko driver
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\MM\\Desktop\\fbc\\lib\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setCapability("marionette", true);
// Aqui puedes añadir todas las capabilities que necesites
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("myProfileName");
options.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, myprofile);
// Se crea el firefox driver con esas options
// Este ya es tu try catch
try{
WebDriver driver = FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("https://google.com");
Thread.sleep(1800);}
```

Comment: Hola Gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo no entiendo muy bien, soy medio novato. ¿Como agrego ese codigo al que ya tengo? Gracias

Comment: Si la respuesta es correcta, por favor marcalá como tal. Se explica mejor en el manual [que hacer cuando responden a mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)